# CheckBoxFor returning previous value in javascript function in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I am using ASP.NET MVC with c#.

I am using CheckBoxFor in my view for a boolean value of RememberMe.

This is my checkboxfor in view:

```
<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RememberMe)%>
```

and fetching value of it in .js function.

By default, it is set to true 
but if I unchecked that box, still it is returning true value to the .js function.

Function for viewModel values:

```
function getViewModel() {
    var viewModel = {
        'UserName': $("#UserName").val(),
        'Password': $("#Password").val(),
        'RememberMe': $("#RememberMe").val()      
    };
    return viewModel;
}
```

It is getting other values correct but RememberMe is true even if I Uncheched it

Please suggest me something.

Comment: any chance of seeing this js function?

Comment: yes.. am adding it to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value attribute of a checkbox  element is fixed -- that's not what you want to examine. This name/value pair is only *sent over HTTP* if the box is checked when the form is submitted.

So instead, look at whether the check-box is checked in your function, and set an the view-model property value accordingly:

```
function getViewModel() {
    var viewModel = {
    'UserName': $("#UserName").val(),
    'Password': $("#Password").val(),
    'RememberMe': $("#RememberMe").is(":checked") ? "true" : "false"
    };
    return viewModel;
}
```

Or whatever values you want passed instead of "true" or "false"